# In the following code, the Month Variable is always entering the else statement block.What changes do i need to make for it to run correctly?

Tags: java

Action performed here and the month is always executed with the else condition.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    tmonthin.setText((((JComboBox) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem()
            .toString()) + "   ");
    Month = tmonthin.getText();
    System.out.println(Month);
    System.out.println("aby");
    int n;
    System.out.println(Month);
    if (Month.equals("March") || "January".equals(Month)
            || "May".equals(Month) || Month == "July" || Month == "August"
            || Month == "October" || Month == "December") {
        System.out.println("abd");
        n = 31;
    } else if (Month == "February") {
        n = 28;
    } else {
        System.out.println("bnbn");
        n = 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"February".equals(Month)`

Comment: Why exactly are you using 3 different types of string comparison (one of which `==` is incorrect)?

Comment: Please use equals() for exact string comparison or equalsIgnoreCase() if it is not case sensitive exact string comparison

Comment: Month.equals("February") and Month == "February"  are not the same in Java. The first one is a content based equality and returns true. The second one is reference based equality, which would return false.

Comment: What is the dataType of Month?? I think you should use tmonthin.getText().toString() while getting the value of that text.